# Fastest way to clamp a real (fixed/floating point) value?

Tags: c, numbers, bit-manipulation, clamp

Is there a more efficient way to clamp real numbers than using if statements or ternary operators?
I want to do this both for doubles and for a 32-bit fixpoint implementation (16.16). I'm **not** asking for code that can handle both cases; they will be handled in separate functions.

Obviously, I can do something like:

```
double clampedA;
double a = calculate();
clampedA = a > MY_MAX ? MY_MAX : a;
clampedA = a < MY_MIN ? MY_MIN : a;
```

or

```
double a = calculate();
double clampedA = a;
if(clampedA > MY_MAX)
    clampedA = MY_MAX;
else if(clampedA < MY_MIN)
    clampedA = MY_MIN;
```

The fixpoint version would use functions/macros for comparisons.

This is done in a performance-critical part of the code, so I'm looking for an as efficient way to do it as possible (which I suspect would involve bit-manipulation)

EDIT: It has to be standard/portable C, platform-specific functionality is not of any interest here. Also, `MY_MIN` and `MY_MAX` are the same type as the value I want clamped (doubles in the examples above).

Comment: I think you could use SSE3 or some similar technology for this, but do not know exactly which commands/how...
You can take a look at: [Saturation arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic)

Comment: Sorry, the question was not clear about platform-requirements. I've edited the question to be a bit cleared.

Comment: I know it has been two and a half years since you asked this question, but I hope you check my answer - a 3x improvement is significant.

Comment: A detail not specified is what precision (relative or absolute) are you willing to trade for speed - if any.     If code requires an in-range `a` to be returned exactly as `a`, then many answers do not meet that hurdle.  If precision is of _no_ concern , then always returning  `(MY_MAX + MY_MIN)/2` will certainly be a fast low-precision answer, and certainly foolish.  Recommend tolerating no more than 1 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) error.

Comment: How would you do it on SSE4 variable (`__m128`)?

Comment: related [most-efficient-elegant-way-to-clip-a-number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9323903/52074)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the 16.16 representation, the simple ternary is unlikely to be bettered speed-wise.

And for doubles, because you need it standard/portable C, bit-fiddling of any kind will end badly.

Even if a bit-fiddle was possible (which I doubt), you'd be relying on the binary representation of doubles. THIS (and their size) IS IMPLEMENTATION-DEPENDENT.

Possibly you could "guess" this using sizeof(double) and then comparing the layout of various double values against their common binary representations, but I think you're on a hiding to nothing.

The best rule is TELL THE COMPILER WHAT YOU WANT (ie ternary), and let it optimise for you.

**EDIT:** Humble pie time. I just tested quinmars idea (below), and it works - if you have IEEE-754 floats. This gave a speedup of about 20% on the code below. IObviously non-portable, but I think there may be a standardised way of asking your compiler if it uses IEEE754 float formats with a #IF...?

```
  double FMIN = 3.13;
  double FMAX = 300.44;

  double FVAL[10] = {-100, 0.23, 1.24, 3.00, 3.5, 30.5, 50 ,100.22 ,200.22, 30000};
  uint64  Lfmin = *(uint64 *)&FMIN;
  uint64  Lfmax = *(uint64 *)&FMAX;

    DWORD start = GetTickCount();

    for (int j=0; j<10000000; ++j)
    {
        uint64 * pfvalue = (uint64 *)&FVAL[0];
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
            *pfvalue++ = (*pfvalue < Lfmin) ? Lfmin : (*pfvalue > Lfmax) ? Lfmax : *pfvalue;
    }

    volatile DWORD hacktime = GetTickCount() - start;

    for (int j=0; j<10000000; ++j)
    {
        double * pfvalue = &FVAL[0];
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
            *pfvalue++ = (*pfvalue < FMIN) ? FMIN : (*pfvalue > FMAX) ? FMAX : *pfvalue;
    }

    volatile DWORD normaltime = GetTickCount() - (start + hacktime);
```

Comment: Assuming IEEE-754 for the floating point case is portable enough for my situation. Thanks for taking the time to follow up.

Comment: The version with `int64_t` will give wrong results when both `FMIN` and `*pfvalue` are less then zero e.g., FMIN=-1, FMAX=1, (*pfvalue)=-0.1; see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427477/fastest-way-to-clamp-a-real-fixed-floating-point-value#429391

Comment: @JFS Ah yes. IEE754 uses sign/magnitude encoding, not 2s complement. So comparisons with negative numbers are flawed. If FMIN and FMAX both >= zero, then you're fine (even if pfvalue is negative). If FMIN or FMAX are zero, all bets are off...

Comment: I wonder if you'd have time to compare my branch-free min/max solution against yours? I'd love some independent validation, especially since I wasn't able to duplicate your results with quinmars version.

Comment: @Mark - I'll see what I can do. Different results are probably because your compiler just optimised a load better than mine!

Answer (score 64):

Both GCC and clang generate beautiful assembly for the following simple, straightforward, portable code:

```
double clamp(double d, double min, double max) {
  const double t = d < min ? min : d;
  return t > max ? max : t;
}
```

`> gcc -O3 -march=native -Wall -Wextra -Wc++-compat -S -fverbose-asm clamp_ternary_operator.c`

GCC-generated assembly:

```
maxsd   %xmm0, %xmm1    # d, min
movapd  %xmm2, %xmm0    # max, max
minsd   %xmm1, %xmm0    # min, max
ret
```

`> clang -O3 -march=native -Wall -Wextra -Wc++-compat -S -fverbose-asm clamp_ternary_operator.c`

Clang-generated assembly:

```
maxsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
minsd   %xmm1, %xmm2
movaps  %xmm2, %xmm0
ret
```

Three instructions (not counting the ret), no branches.  Excellent.

This was tested with GCC 4.7 and clang 3.2 on Ubuntu 13.04 with a Core i3 M 350.
On a side note, the straightforward C++ code calling std::min and std::max generated the same assembly.

This is for doubles. And for int, both GCC and clang generate assembly with five instructions (not counting the ret) and no branches. Also excellent.

I don't currently use fixed-point, so I will not give an opinion on fixed-point.

Comment: Great.  Slightly better than [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/453171/2410359) as it symmetrically handles `min` and/or `max` when one/both are Not-A-number.  It also preserve sign with `d = -0.0`!

Comment: Using `if (d < min)` and `if (d > max)` also gives me the same assembly code. It's interesting to see, however, that using `if (d < min)` and `else if (d > max)` generates a different output (there's one jump instruction).

Comment: Exact. This should be the right answer.
This is a compiler analysis for the question: https://godbolt.org/z/ZW4W6F

Comment: Tested with MSVC 2019, also compiles to no branches (at least for floats).

Answer (score 40):

Old question, but I was working on this problem today (with doubles/floats).

The best approach is to use SSE MINSS/MAXSS for floats and SSE2 MINSD/MAXSD for doubles.  These are branchless and take one clock cycle each, and are easy to use thanks to compiler intrinsics.  They confer more than an order of magnitude increase in performance compared with clamping with std::min/max.

You may find that surprising.  I certainly did!  Unfortunately VC++ 2010 uses simple comparisons for std::min/max even when /arch:SSE2 and /FP:fast are enabled.  I can't speak for other compilers.

Here's the necessary code to do this in VC++:

```
#include <mmintrin.h>

float minss ( float a, float b )
{
    // Branchless SSE min.
    _mm_store_ss( &a, _mm_min_ss(_mm_set_ss(a),_mm_set_ss(b)) );
    return a;
}

float maxss ( float a, float b )
{
    // Branchless SSE max.
    _mm_store_ss( &a, _mm_max_ss(_mm_set_ss(a),_mm_set_ss(b)) );
    return a;
}

float clamp ( float val, float minval, float maxval )
{
    // Branchless SSE clamp.
    // return minss( maxss(val,minval), maxval );

    _mm_store_ss( &val, _mm_min_ss( _mm_max_ss(_mm_set_ss(val),_mm_set_ss(minval)), _mm_set_ss(maxval) ) );
    return val;
}
```

The double precision code is the same except with xxx_sd instead.

Edit: Initially I wrote the clamp function as commented.  But looking at the assembler output I noticed that the VC++ compiler wasn't smart enough to cull the redundant move.  One less instruction. :)

Comment: Is there an equivalent for these functions for GCC?

Comment: Yes, for GCC x86 use `__builtin_ia32_storess`, `__builtin_ia32_maxss`, __builtin_ia32_minss` are the equivalent functions and the `xmmintrin.h` header for SSE1 instructions. Pass `-mmmx -msse` to the compiler, you may need `-mfpmath=sse(,x87)` as well. Intrinsics are also available for ARM Neon and AltiVec. See   [X86 Built-in functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html) for more details.

Comment: It's not possible for the compiler to replace `std::min` and `std::max` with the intrinsics in the general case, because the intrinsics provide the IEEE754 specified result for `min(2.0, NaN)` and `min(NaN, 2.0)` (which is `2.0` in both cases) while a naive implementation based on a single comparison will return an inconsistent result based on the parameter order. C99 and C++11 provide `fmax` and `fmin`, and a clever compiler will replace these with efficient inline implementations.

Comment: Is there a switching penalty for using SSE instructions, or interleaving them with standard floating point ops?

Comment: This seems really helpful --- does anyone know of a full implementation anywhere, e.g., with proper #ifdef's for gcc and clang etc.?

Answer (score 18):

If your processor has a fast instruction for absolute value (as the x86 does), you can do a branchless min and max which will be faster than an `if` statement or ternary operation.

```
min(a,b) = (a + b - abs(a-b)) / 2
max(a,b) = (a + b + abs(a-b)) / 2
```

If one of the terms is zero (as is often the case when you're clamping) the code simplifies a bit further:

```
max(a,0) = (a + abs(a)) / 2
```

When you're combining both operations you can replace the two `/2` into a single `/4` or `*0.25` to save a step.

The following code is over 3x faster than ternary on my Athlon II X2, when using the optimization for FMIN=0.

```
double clamp(double value)
{
    double temp = value + FMAX - abs(value-FMAX);
#if FMIN == 0
    return (temp + abs(temp)) * 0.25;
#else
    return (temp + (2.0*FMIN) + abs(temp-(2.0*FMIN))) * 0.25;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Wow - nice idea! I suspect on certain CPUs/compilers this could actually be slower than ternary if `abs(a)` isn't inlined/optimised nicely...

Comment: In C#, usig Math.Abs, this approach is slower.

Comment: I would expect `fabs(value-FMAX)` rather than `int abs(int j)`.

Comment: @chux I tested with a C++ compiler which might have used the proper function via overloading.

Comment: Weakness: This approach can incur serve loss of precision.  `FMAX` values greater than `value` can lose precision in the result.  If `FMAX` is 10x `value`, then 1 decimal digit can be lost.  Worst case, the clamped return value is always 0.0.

Comment: Would you need to say `min(a,b) = (a + b - abs(static_cast<int>(a-b))) / 2` for unsigned values?  Without the static_cast<int>, `a-b` could be a very large value if `b > a`, which would in turn give an incorrect value.

Answer (score 14):

Ternary operator is really the way to go, because most compilers are able to compile them into a native hardware operation that uses a conditional move instead of a branch (and thus avoids the mispredict penalty and pipeline bubbles and so on). **Bit-manipulation is likely to cause a load-hit-store**.

In particular, PPC and x86 with SSE2 have a hardware op that could be expressed as an intrinsic something like this:

```
double fsel( double a, double b, double c ) {
  return a >= 0 ? b : c; 
}
```

The advantage is that it does this inside the pipeline, without causing a branch. In fact, if your compiler uses the intrinsic, you can use it to implement your clamp directly:

```
inline double clamp ( double a, double min, double max ) 
{
   a = fsel( a - min , a, min );
   return fsel( a - max, max, a );
}
```

I strongly suggest you **avoid bit-manipulation of doubles using integer operations**. On most modern CPUs there is no direct means of moving data between double and int registers other than by taking a round trip to the dcache. This will cause a data hazard called a load-hit-store which basically empties out the CPU pipeline until the memory write has completed (usually around 40 cycles or so).

The exception to this is if the double values are already in memory and not in a register: in that case there is no danger of a load-hit-store. However your example indicates you've just calculated the double and returned it from a function which means it's likely to still be in XMM1.

Comment: one note about the ternary operator:  Test how the types and order of the inputs affects the optimized output.  I worked on a compiler where `A > B ? A : B` consistently generated an MAX instruction, but `A < B ? B : A` did not.

Comment: @AShelly : You gotta wonder what was in the mind of the person who wrote that compiler.

Comment: Works nicely all FP numbers!  It even preserved the sign with `a == -0.0`!  Only values/limits I had some concern involved some asymmetry with Not-a-numbers - Allows `min` to be a Not--a-number and nicely ignores the `min`.  Yet if `max` is NAN, result is NAN.  Could be made symmetric with a different code than `return fsel( a - max, max, a );`

Answer (score 8):

Rather than testing and branching, I normally use this format for clamping:

```
clampedA = fmin(fmax(a,MY_MIN),MY_MAX);
```

Although I have never done any performance analysis on the compiled code.

Comment: Nice.  Any alternative code should be tested against this as the standard to beat in performance, yet match in functionality.

Comment: +1 Don't know about speed, but when performance isn't a concern, this is definitely cleaner than the solutions involving ternaries, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The bits of IEEE 754 floating point are ordered in a way that if you compare the bits interpreted as an integer you get the same results as if you would compare them as floats directly. So if you find or know a way to clamp integers you can use it for (IEEE 754) floats as well. Sorry, I don't know a faster way.

If you have the floats stored in an arrays you can consider to use some CPU extensions like SSE3, as rkj said. You can take a look at liboil it does all the dirty work for you. Keeps your program portable and uses faster cpu instructions if possible. (I'm not sure tho how OS/compiler-independent liboil is).

Comment: Only for positive floats. If the signs may be mixed, you need to note them, return early if different, take the absolute values and reverse ordering if negative. In short, optimization only works for positive floats.

Answer (score 4):

Realistically, no decent compiler will make a difference between an if() statement and a ?: expression. The code is simple enough that they'll be able to spot the possible paths. That said, your two examples are not identical. The equivalent code using ?: would be

```
a = (a > MAX) ? MAX : ((a < MIN) ? MIN : a);
```

as that avoid the A < MIN test when a > MAX. Now that could make a difference, as the compiler otherwise would have to spot the relation between the two tests.

If clamping is rare, you can test the need to clamp with a single test:

```
if (abs(a - (MAX+MIN)/2) > ((MAX-MIN)/2)) ...
```

E.g. with MIN=6 and MAX=10, this will first shift a down by 8, then check if it lies between -2 and +2. Whether this saves anything depends a lot on the relative cost of branching.

Comment: You'd be surprised -- the last time I looked at its disassembly, my compiler properly cooked a ternary expression into the appropriate conditional-move opcode, but turned an equivalent if/else block into two compares and branches.

Comment: I liked the idea to clamp with a single test ;)

Comment: I was looking for a fast way to test if a point is inside a bounding box. This means testing if an X value is between a max and a min, and the same for a Y value. Your suggestion looks promising.

Comment: 1) Expect `fabs()` than `int abs(int)`  2) Edge condition issues with precision loss in `fabs(a - (MAX+MIN)/2) > ((MAX-MIN)/2)`.  First method does not have those problems.

Comment: @MSalters just wondering about this ```#define CLAMP(VAL, LO, HI) VAL = ((VAL < LO) ? LO : ((VAL > HI) ? HI : VAL)```

do you think compiler will optimise this sufficiently?  I'm using this in 64bit arm GCC.

Comment: @Ganindu: Compilers have improved definitely over the last decade. I wouldn't worry. Worse case it shows up in profiling.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possibly faster implementation similar to [@Roddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427477/fastest-way-to-clamp-a-real-fixed-floating-point-value#427580):

```
typedef int64_t i_t;
typedef double  f_t;

static inline
i_t i_tmin(i_t x, i_t y) {
  return (y + ((x - y) & -(x < y))); // min(x, y)
}

static inline
i_t i_tmax(i_t x, i_t y) {
  return (x - ((x - y) & -(x < y))); // max(x, y)
}

f_t clip_f_t(f_t f, f_t fmin, f_t fmax)
{
#ifndef TERNARY
  assert(sizeof(i_t) == sizeof(f_t));
  //assert(not (fmin < 0 and (f < 0 or is_negative_zero(f))));
  //XXX assume IEEE-754 compliant system (lexicographically ordered floats)
  //XXX break strict-aliasing rules
  const i_t imin = *(i_t*)&fmin;
  const i_t imax = *(i_t*)&fmax;
  const i_t i    = *(i_t*)&f;
  const i_t iclipped = i_tmin(imax, i_tmax(i, imin));

#ifndef INT_TERNARY
  return *(f_t *)&iclipped;
#else /* INT_TERNARY */
  return i < imin ? fmin : (i > imax ? fmax : f); 
#endif /* INT_TERNARY */

#else /* TERNARY */
  return fmin > f ? fmin : (fmax < f ? fmax : f);
#endif /* TERNARY */
}
```

See [Compute the minimum (min) or maximum (max) of two integers without branching](http://www.cs.utk.edu/~vose/c-stuff/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax) and [Comparing floating point numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm)

> The IEEE float and double formats were
>   designed so that the numbers are
>   “lexicographically ordered”, which –
>   in the words of IEEE architect William
>   Kahan means “if two floating-point
>   numbers in the same format are ordered
>   ( say x < y ), then they are ordered
>   the same way when their bits are
>   reinterpreted as Sign-Magnitude
>   integers.”

A test program:

```
/** gcc -std=c99 -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -lm -Wall *.c -o clip_double && clip_double */
#include <assert.h> 
#include <iso646.h>  // not, and
#include <math.h>    // isnan()
#include <stdbool.h> // bool
#include <stdint.h>  // int64_t
#include <stdio.h>

static 
bool is_negative_zero(f_t x) 
{
  return x == 0 and 1/x < 0;
}

static inline 
f_t range(f_t low, f_t f, f_t hi) 
{
  return fmax(low, fmin(f, hi));
}

static const f_t END = 0./0.;

#define TOSTR(f, fmin, fmax, ff) ((f) == (fmin) ? "min" :       \
                  ((f) == (fmax) ? "max" :      \
                   (is_negative_zero(ff) ? "-0.":   \
                    ((f) == (ff) ? "f" : #f))))

static int test(f_t p[], f_t fmin, f_t fmax, f_t (*fun)(f_t, f_t, f_t)) 
{
  assert(isnan(END));
  int failed_count = 0;
  for ( ; ; ++p) {
    const f_t clipped  = fun(*p, fmin, fmax), expected = range(fmin, *p, fmax);
    if(clipped != expected and not (isnan(clipped) and isnan(expected))) {
      failed_count++;
      fprintf(stderr, "error: got: %s, expected: %s\t(min=%g, max=%g, f=%g)\n", 
          TOSTR(clipped,  fmin, fmax, *p), 
          TOSTR(expected, fmin, fmax, *p), fmin, fmax, *p);
    }
    if (isnan(*p))
      break;
  }
  return failed_count;
}  

int main(void)
{
  int failed_count = 0;
  f_t arr[] = { -0., -1./0., 0., 1./0., 1., -1., 2, 
        2.1, -2.1, -0.1, END};
  f_t minmax[][2] = { -1, 1,  // min, max
               0, 2, };

  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(minmax) / sizeof(*minmax)); ++i) 
    failed_count += test(arr, minmax[i][0], minmax[i][1], clip_f_t);      

  return failed_count & 0xFF;
}
```

In console:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -lm *.c -o clip_double && ./clip_double
```

It prints:

```
error: got: min, expected: -0.  (min=-1, max=1, f=0)
error: got: f, expected: min    (min=-1, max=1, f=-1.#INF)
error: got: f, expected: min    (min=-1, max=1, f=-2.1)
error: got: min, expected: f    (min=-1, max=1, f=-0.1)
```

Comment: Re: `is_negative_zero`, Is there a reason why you did not use C99's math.h `signbit` function (combined with `x == 0`), and instead used `1.0 / x < 0` to check the sign of zero?

Comment: @mctylr: don't remember. `signbit` also seems to [work](http://ideone.com/zqMl0).

Answer (score 1):

I tried the SSE approach to this myself, and the assembly output looked quite a bit cleaner, so I was encouraged at first, but after timing it thousands of times, it was actually quite a bit slower. It does indeed look like the VC++ compiler isn't smart enough to know what you're really intending, and it appears to move things back and forth between the XMM registers and memory when it shouldn't. That said, I don't know why the compiler isn't smart enough to use the SSE min/max instructions on the ternary operator when it seems to use SSE instructions for all floating point calculations anyway. On the other hand, if you're compiling for PowerPC, you can use the fsel intrinsic on the FP registers, and it's way faster.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above, fmin/fmax functions work well (in gcc, with -ffast-math). Although gfortran has patterns to use IA instructions corresponding to max/min, g++ does not. In icc one must use instead std::min/max, because icc doesn't allow short-cutting the specification of how fmin/fmax work with non-finite operands.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents in C++. Probably not any different than use ternary operators and hopefully no branching code is generated

```
template <typename T>
inline T clamp(T val, T lo, T hi) {
    return std::max(lo, std::min(hi, val));
}
```

Comment: Just for whomever comes across this: C++17's `<algorithm>` header introduced [`std::clamp(n, low, high [, compare])`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you want to limit a value "a" to a range between MY_MIN and MY_MAX.  The type of "a" is a double.  You did not specify the type of MY_MIN or MY_MAX.

The simple expression:

```
clampedA = (a > MY_MAX)? MY_MAX : (a < MY_MIN)? MY_MIN : a;
```

should do the trick.

I think there may be a small optimization to be made if MY_MAX  and MY_MIN happen to be integers:

```
int b = (int)a;
clampedA = (b > MY_MAX)? (double)MY_MAX : (b < MY_MIN)? (double)MY_MIN : a;
```

By changing to integer comparisons, it is possible you might get a slight speed advantage.

Comment: Even with `MY_MIN,MY_MAX` as `int`, this approach fails if `a` is not near the `int` range as `(int)a` is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use fast absolute value instructions, check out this snipped of code I found in [minicomputer](http://minicomputer.sourceforge.net/), which clamps a float to the range [0,1]

```
clamped = 0.5*(fabs(x)-fabs(x-1.0f) + 1.0f);
```

(I simplified the code a bit).  We can think about it as taking two values, one reflected to be >0

```
fabs(x)
```

and the other reflected about 1.0 to be <1.0

```
1.0-fabs(x-1.0)
```

And we take the average of them.  If it is in range, then both values will be the same as x, so their average will again be x.  If it is out of range, then one of the values will be x, and the other will be x flipped over the "boundary" point, so their average will be precisely the boundary point.

Comment: Lots of precision loss, starting with about `x  < 0.25`. With `values < DBL__EPSILON`, result loses all precision.