# How can I best make a function which functions similar as modulus but stops at max without using conditionals?

Tags: python, math, limit

I want to create a function which will function like this:

```py
def ceil(i: int, max: int) -> int:
    return max if i > max else i
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do this without using conditions.

I think it should be possible to do the function with simple math. But I can't figure out how.

I don't want to use any built in functions.

Comment: `max` is poor name - it's built-in function. if I get what you want - `return min(i, ceil_value)`

Comment: thank you but thats not my question

Answer (score 2):

The following function will do the trick:

```
def ceil(i: int, max: int) -> int:
    return min(i, max)
```

But at this point you don't event need the function! :)

```
ceil = min
```

and that's it.

P.S. I agree with the comment saying `max` is not a great name choice.

---

Based on the discussion from the comment section:

To avoid conditionals that `min` or `abs` builin functions have in Python you could do:

```
custom_abs = lambda v: v * ((v>0) - (v<0))
ceil = lambda a, b: (a + b - custom_abs(a-b)) / 2
```

However, I still think you would have conditionals in CPython implementation due to type checking etc.

Comment: are you sure the min functions does not contain any conditions?

Comment: @mama Why do you care?

Comment: because I don't want to use if statements

Comment: @mama Why not ?

Comment: Do you allow your CPU to use branching? :>

Comment: I think its possible to do it with math.

Comment: `ceil = lambda a, b: (a + b - abs(a-b)) / 2` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7424900/1577204

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/77195cd44b2506cda88a3cfc98918526068b1d46/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1708

Comment: Thats the source code for min and max - there is too many if statements

Comment: And here is the sourcecode for abs which also is using if statements https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31ff96712e8f89ac1056c2da880b44650002219f/Objects/abstract.c#L1377

Comment: @LukaszWiecek The absolute value function still probably contains the conditional unfortunately.

Comment: `abs = lambda v: v * ((v>0) - (v<0))` how about this one?

Comment: That's clever, I think it works now without conditionals if you combine both of those! I would put it in the answer. I hope there's no more conditionals lurking anywhere

Comment: @RichardKYu I suspect that **many** conditionals get used to evaluate those. Or **anything** written in Python. They're asking about the wrong language.

Answer (score 1):

Code below works for `-2**32 <= |a - b| <= 2**32`
In this case, the `sign` bit of the integer is the 31st bit (counting from `0`)

```
def ceil(a: int, b: int):
    return -a * ((a - b) >> 31) - b * ((b - a) >> 31)
```

Answer (score -1):

So this is what I came up with - it is not pretty but it works.

```
def ceil(x, top=10): return (
    1-1//(1+x))*(1-(
        top-top//x
    )//top)*x+(
        top-top//x
    )//top*top

for i in range(1,21):
    print(ceil(i))
```